# include entire Javascript module into Blazor Server

Tags: javascript, blazor, form-designer

I'm pretty new to web programming and blazor. I found an open source form designer on github that is written in javascript.
See here: https://github.com/Draggable/formeo
I would like to embed this designer in a blazor server web application. Do you think this is possible and do you have any advice on how to do it?

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but it won't work - you're trying to mix oil and water.  Forms in Blazor are defined in *Razor* and *C#*.  You need to roll up your sleeves and go through so basic Blazor tutorials.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Building a drag and drop form designer from scratch by myself is a bit heavy, so I wanted to use an existing solution, but there are no promising solutions in Blazor, C# etc. so i hoped i could use this one...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a js file, let's call it `site.js`:

In your `_host.cshtml` you can insert the tag:

`<script src="js/site.js"></script>`

After that, in a component you can use

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop      @*This can go in your _Imports.razor so it will apply to the whole project*@
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;   @*Dependency Injection*@
.
.
.
@code {
    private async Task myFunction(){
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myFunctionName", myFunctionParameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So as described in the Readme "To start building forms with this module include formeo.min.js and formeo.min.css ...." so i need to include those two files in my project and tag them in the _Host.cshtml right ? then create a file as you described to call a method that generates the object "const editor = new FormeoEditor(options)" ?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm not familiar with the script but that should work, just try it out. Take attention that, at least on my VS, when I'm adding a script/stylesheet to `_host.cshtml` it adds a `~/`, which doesn't work since I already have a `<base href="~/" />` before